# What is the name and type of this plant?

Tags: houseplants

This plant is easy to grow even if you dont water it. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the Zig Zag plant, Euphorbia tithymaloides, though it would have been helpful to see the whole plant as well to be certain. It's a type of succulent plant, but does need watering during the growing season, though relatively sparingly. If you're growing it indoors, it will appreciate sunlight year round **except** during the summer months. Some information here https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/Pedilanthus_tithymaloides.htm. Be aware that the sap of this plant can be an irritant on the skin.